# Java2D - How to rotate an image and save the result

Tags: java, image, rotation

I'm making a game where some objects rotate to face what they're shooting at.  There's a delay in between shooting and I want the object to keep facing where it is until it shoots again.  I know how to load images and I know how to rotate them using AffineTransform.  But with this I need to calculate the rotate every time the object gets drawn.

So my question is how can I rotate an image and save the result into a new image that would get displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***how can I rotate an image and save the result into a new image that would get displayed?***

Create a new `BufferedImage`. Get hold of a `Graphics` object (through [`BufferedImage.getGraphics()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getGraphics%28%29). Paint the rotated image onto this buffered image, and save the image in an array or a map based on its rotation (so that it easy to look it up when you need it).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response.  Should I make a rotation for all 360 degrees?  The images are fairly small so would having one for every 2 or 5 degrees work just as well?

Comment: If I where you I would set it as a compile time constant. Something like `NUM_ROTATIONS` and create an `BufferedImage[NUM_ROTATIONS]` to hold the sprites, and rotate each one by `i * 360.0 / NUM_ROTATIONS`. Then you can try out different rotations easily.

Comment: You'll be able to soon enough :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Affline transform only works with perfect squares. The following code
>   is used to take any rectangle image and rotate it correctly. To do
>   this it chooses a center point that is half the greater length and
>   tricks the library to think the image is a perfect square, then it
>   does the rotation and tells the library where to find the correct top
>   left point. The special cases in each orientation happen when the
>   extra image that doesn't exist is either on the left or on top of the
>   image being rotated. In both cases the point is adjusted by the
>   difference in the longer side and the shorter side to get the point at
>   the  correct top left corner of the image. NOTE: the x and y axes also
>   rotate with the image so where width > height the adjustments always
>   happen on the y axis and where the height > width the adjustments
>   happen on the x axis.

```
private BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage image, double _theta, int _thetaInDegrees) {

    AffineTransform xform = new AffineTransform();

    if (image.getWidth() > image.getHeight()) {
        xform.setToTranslation(0.5 * image.getWidth(), 0.5 * image.getWidth());
        xform.rotate(_theta);

        int diff = image.getWidth() - image.getHeight();

        switch (_thetaInDegrees) {
            case 90:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getWidth(), -0.5 * image.getWidth() + diff);
                break;
            case 180:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getWidth(), -0.5 * image.getWidth() + diff);
                break;
            default:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getWidth(), -0.5 * image.getWidth());
                break;
        }
    } else if (image.getHeight() > image.getWidth()) {
        xform.setToTranslation(0.5 * image.getHeight(), 0.5 * image.getHeight());
        xform.rotate(_theta);

        int diff = image.getHeight() - image.getWidth();

        switch (_thetaInDegrees) {
            case 180:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getHeight() + diff, -0.5 * image.getHeight());
                break;
            case 270:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getHeight() + diff, -0.5 * image.getHeight());
                break;
            default:
                xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getHeight(), -0.5 * image.getHeight());
                break;
        }
    } else {
        xform.setToTranslation(0.5 * image.getWidth(), 0.5 * image.getHeight());
        xform.rotate(_theta);
        xform.translate(-0.5 * image.getHeight(), -0.5 * image.getWidth());
    }

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(xform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);

    return op.filter(image, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to clone images:

```
BufferedImage source = new BufferedImage(50, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR); 

BufferedImage target = new BufferedImage(50, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
Graphics2D tg = target.createGraphics();

AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.rotate(2);

tg.drawImage(source, at, null);
```

P.S.: Ignore my previous answer, I misread the question. Sorry.