# rotate Image without re-size image in java

Tags: java, image, swing, image-rotation

i write this codes :

```
BufferedImage image;
BufferedImage im = image;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("jet.png"));
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawImage(image, 100, 100, Color.BLACK, null);
        image = rotateImage(-45);
        g2.drawImage(image, 250, 100, Color.BLACK, null);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    }

    public BufferedImage rotateImage(int degress) {

    double deg = Math.toRadians(degress);
    double xrot = image.getWidth()/2 ;
    double yrot = image.getHeight() /2;
    AffineTransform xt = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(deg, xrot, yrot);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(xt, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    return op.filter(image, im);

    }
}
```

and output is :

[image]

and new image size is change!!! i want to rotate this image , and its important new image size whitout change

i want some code to rotate image whitout resize image ,  Like this

[image]

Comment: you can replace with one image by the other image.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i want use just one image !!!!

Comment: Have you tried the Scalr library, it can maintain your image size, and rotate it. But if image is not a square, then ofcourse its dimensions will change.

Comment: @NaniNakhli, add answer, good?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko this line have error:
 GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Oops ,again image was resize !

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157459/java2d-how-to-rotate-an-image-and-save-the-result/31136096#31136096)

Answer (score 2):

The effect shown is characteristic of [`AffineTransformOp#filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/AffineTransformOp.html#filter-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-): "The coordinates of the rectangle returned by `getBounds2D(BufferedImage)` are not necessarily the same as the coordinates of the `BufferedImage` returned by this method." Instead, draw the image into `BufferedImage` having a rotated graphics context, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4288714/230513). Use [`RenderingHints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html), such as `VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON` and `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR`, as needed.

Comment: this is example of my code !
my code have 11 Image for draw , and i want rotate one of them

Comment: It might be easier if you make the background transparent using one of the approaches mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27335373/230513).

Answer (score 2):

First of all:

1. Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` and don't forget the super.paintComponent(...) at the start of the method.
2. Don't do I/O in a painting method. Read the image in the constructor of the class

When you rotate a square other than 90, 180, 270, etc. degrees, the size of the square will change. So, the problem is the version of the drawImage(...) method you are using:

```
g2.drawImage(image, 100, 100, Color.BLACK, null);
```

Instead of using the drawImage() method to draw the background and the image you can paint the background and the image separately so you can control the size of the background:

```
//g2.drawImage(image, 100, 100, Color.BLACK, null);
g2.setColor( Color.BLACK );
g2.fillRect(100, 100, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
g2.drawImage(image, 100, 100, null);
image = rotateImage(-45);
g2.fillRect(250, 100, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
g2.drawImage(image, 250, 100, null);
```

Comment: tnx for your answer 
i draw background to show image size !
and orginal size image is importnat Because i want to use <code>image.getWidth()</code> and <code>image.getHeight()</code> in my code for other work !